# javaScript text validation by regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check if a string starts with `http://` in java script

What I have is

```
if(!txt.match(/^http:/)) {}  // this only works for http:
```

I need to make it work for `http://`

can any one suggest a solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `\` chars, also for checking is better to use `test` method.

```
if(!(/^http:\/\//.test(txt))) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

```
txt.substr(0, 7) === "http://"
```